# How to use a service account with Google's python api and drive?

Tags: python, google-api, pycrypto, google-api-python-client, pkcs#12

I try to write python 2.7 script to upload a file into my personal google drive folder.

After several problems I stuck know. This is my current error:

> NotImplementedError: PKCS12 format is not supported by the PyCrpto library. Try converting to a "PEM" (openssl pkcs12 -in xxxxx.p12 -nodes -nocerts > privatekey.pem) or using PyOpenSSL if native code is an option.

I already tried to run this commands, as mentiod in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17993604/2321643) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18042823/2321643).

```
openssl pkcs12 -in privatekey.p12 -nodes -nocerts > privatekey.pem
openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -in privatekey.pem -passin pass:notasecret -topk8 -out pk.pem
```

my privatekey.p12 downloaded from the new modern fancy google developers console was original named `something-0123eed.json` and looked like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
{
  "private_key_id": "9ced108fe72345373b75b03d7e967a3f8c0084ca",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxe91Tr6RHs57LKX2HivFmOQwcFoJkUPrbB6Gwy8prE...Pc9jNExo5Krp1kLrkJYxAOmUWxWwPJ4pCx7Lxc6uQQnAlKyRmnfVpdS2I0\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "0KsVeSAa91UtEGvY9lil@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "0KsVeSAa91UtEGvY9lil.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "type": "service_account"
}
```

My python code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/env python2.7

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
import httplib2
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials


credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        service_account_name='0KsVeSAa91UtEGvY9lil@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
        private_key=key,
        scope = [
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly'
        ]
)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

drive_folder_id = 'jhIKHOG6supMhpjPJFHffZarwxP6'


service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)


media_body = MediaFileUpload('/path/to/superfile.gpg'), mimetype='application/pgp-encrypted')
body = {
        'title': 'superfile.gpg',
        'description': '',
        'mimeType': 'application/pgp-encrypted',
        'parents': [{'id': drive_folder_id}]
}

file = service.files().insert(
        body=body,
        media_body=media_body).execute()
```

1: (of course, I changed the values with junk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the [answer in this gist](https://gist.github.com/vircheck/6292176#convert-you-certificate):

```
openssl pkcs12 -passin pass:notasecret -in privatekey.p12 -nocerts -passout pass:notasecret -out key.pem
openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -in key.pem -passin pass:notasecret -topk8 -out privatekey.pem
rm key.pem
```

But before this, I had to regenerate a new privat key but in P12 format.

[image: generate new P12 key]

Comment: The debug message from the `google datastore` package suggests the following: 'Try converting to a "PEM" (`openssl pkcs12 -in xxxxx.p12 -nodes -nocerts > privatekey.pem`)'.

Comment: But the result of that is one where you have to remove the header manually, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24618630/2452770).